# How to read the image location from firestore without the token and alt

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am successfully uploading a file to the firestore but when I try to fetch it, I get this is return `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<appname>-7cd80.appspot.com/o/profileimages%2F1710350330937-profile.jpg?alt=media&token=<a long string of numbers>`

I just need the `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<appname>-7cd80.appspot.com/o/profileimages%2F1710350330937-profile.jpg` part

```
const handleImage = () => {
  const metadata = {
    contentType: `image/${get_extension(image)}`
  };

  function get_extension(url) {
    let extension = url.toLowerCase().split(".").pop();

    return extension; // png, mp4, jpeg etc.
  }
  const filename = new Date().getTime() + image.substring(image.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

  console.log("image", filename);

  const storageRef = ref(storage, 'profileimages/' + filename);

  // const metadata = getMetadata(storageRef);

  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image, metadata );

  uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
    (snapshot) => {
      const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case 'paused':
          console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case 'running':
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    }, 
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }, 
    () => {
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
        const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userId);
        updateDoc(docRef, {
          image: downloadURL,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Document successfully updated!");
          getUser();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
        });
      });
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: FYI you are uploading the file to Cloud Storage, not Firestore.  Firestore is a database and Cloud Storage is simply a key/value store where the keys are paths and the values are the thing you uploaded, with metadata.

Comment: You can't realistically remove that token from the URL and expect it to work.  It's necessary to allow anonymous access to the file.  You should store the entire URL and use the entire URL in order to provide access to clients.  If this is somehow not actually what you want, you should consider alternatives using GCP's interface to Cloud Storage and not Firebase's, which are discussed in the duplicates.

Comment: Damn. I wish they hadn't closed it. The other "solutions" aren't really solutions

Comment: Well, you have the same question.  If there is something special about your situation, you should ask a new question and make it clear what your high level objective is, the solutions you tried that didn't work, and be very very clear why you cannot have that token in the URL (because like I said, it needs to be there - you cannot "solve" it away because you don't like it).

Comment: So, you are saying this token is part of the image and should display the image? I was under the impression my image wasn't showing because of that stuff after the .jpg

Comment: The token is part of the URL that fetches the content.  None of the content of the image is embedded in that URL - the servers that respond to the URL send the content, and you must use the entire URL exactly as you received it from the getDownloadUrl API.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I wonder why it's not showing up then. It shows error loading preview. hmm. Ok. Thanks again